# What to do next after making machine learning model?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am studying machine learning course online and I am curious what I am going to do with the machine learning I made next. How can I save the test and predicted table and how can I use the trained machine learning model to my newest data? I'm using python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving ml model using Pickle

```
# save the model to disk


filename = 'model.sav'

pickle.dump(model, open(filename, 'wb'))

# load the model from disk

loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))

result = loaded_model.predict(new_point)
```

Here new_point  is 2D numpy array [[]] example 2  points with 3 features

```
[[x11,x12,x13],

[x21,x22,x23]]
```

For more information visit https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-machine-learning-models-python-scikit-learn/